# UITableviewcell content updating reflects to other cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using 8 cells in a tableview. Each cell having group of components like UIButton, UILabel and UISlider. When I update 6th cell, it reflects to 1st cell. Similarly, if I update 7th cell, it reflects to 2nd cell.

Delete cell code:

```
{
 [buttonarray removeObjectAtIndex:delpath.row];
 viewcount--;

ListCell1 *cell=(ListCell1 *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:delpath];

cell.slider.value=0;
cell.qlabel.text=@"1";
cell.slabel.text=@"1";
cell.n=1;
[cell.button1 setTitle:@"240" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


for (int m=0; m<7; m++)
{
    [[cell.myarray objectAtIndex:m]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Num2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIButton *but=[cell.myarray objectAtIndex:m];
    but.tag=0;
}

 [self->table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:delpath, nil]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[table reloadData];
delpath=NULL;
}
```

when pressing button

```
-(void)buttonpressed:(id)sender
{
  viewcount++;
table.delegate=self;
table.dataSource=self;
//UIView *middleview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,300,200)];
[buttonarray addObject:sender];
[table reloadData];
}
```

Code for tableview

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return viewcount;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSString *MyIdentifier=@"mycell";

 ListCell1 *cell = (ListCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil)
{
 cell = [[ListCell1 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
UIButton *b=[buttonarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
 b.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
 cell.imageView.image=b.imageView.image;
 return cell;
 }
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
ListCell1 *cell1 = (ListCell1 *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell1 addSubview:delbutton];
 delpath=indexPath;
 return;
 }
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 100.0;
}
```

Comment: ***Unrelated*** to Xcode.

Comment: hahaa...sory frndz i dont understand ur code :( so please ..put more clear code :) thanks :)

Comment: can you give me a sample code for adding comp in cell and how to delete that cell without any changes of values

Comment: Could you provide the code for - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Comment: check it in question i had added it now by editing.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens because UIKit re-uses cells in a UITableView. Therefore, when you add UI components to that cell the same ones will be re-used on different rows.

In short, you need to clear/rebuild your UI everytime the cell is updated.

Comment: I got the same problem in here. So how can i solve it programmatically