# UITableviewcell content updating reflects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

i have added three `UIButtons` to the each row of the `UITableViewCell`.

When i select a `UIButton` it changes it colour to black. The problem was those colour changes were affected to the other cell's buttons in the table i just saw it when i scroll down through the table.

this link also explaining the same problem->[UITableviewcell content updating reflects to other cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278144/uitableviewcell-content-updating-reflects-to-other-cell)

i could not find any answer to this problem in iOS.

this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custCell"];

    UIButton *btn1=[cell viewWithTag:101];
    btn1.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [btn1 setTag:(indexPath.row*3)+1];

    UIButton *btn2=[cell viewWithTag:102];
    btn2.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [btn2 setTag:(indexPath.row*3)+2];

    UIButton *btn3=[cell viewWithTag:103];
    btn3.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [btn3 setTag:(indexPath.row*3)+3];
rerutn cell;
```

this i my button action method

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"tag %ld",(long)button.tag);
    if(button.backgroundColor==[UIColor blackColor]){
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    }
    else if(button.backgroundColor==[UIColor clearColor]){
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

nothin fancy in this code. How can i solve this problem programmatically.. Thank You..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableviewcell content updating reflects to other cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278144/uitableviewcell-content-updating-reflects-to-other-cell)

Comment: Yes. Do you have any solutions???

Comment: Use the same in cellforrowatindex which you have done in IBAction

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custCell"];
```

With

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil){

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"custCell"];
        }
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: it was same as before. not effected to any. problem satay as same

Answer (score 1):

make UITableViewCell and  add UIButton and tag them with storyboard.

```
@interface TblCellCategoryCell:UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn3;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `UITableView` reuses the cells instead of creating new cells. So suppose you change the color of your cell with index 2 so whenever `UITableView` will reuse that cell it will show the previously created cell with changed color button.

For your specific problem you are resetting the tag of your buttons always so the next time you try to get button from `viewWithTag` it will not return any button at all or will return wrong button.

Comment: so any solutions??

Comment: Are you using Storyboard files or nib files to create your cell or are you creating cells in code?

Comment: i was using StoryBoard.. will it be solved if i create the cell programmatically

Comment: Use Storyboard only, create a subclass of UITableViewCell and use control drag from the button to your UITableViewCell subclass to generate references of your buttons in your code and then use those references instead of using viewWithTag

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowatIndexPth instead of this line

> btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

Use below Code

```
if (btn1.isSelected) {
    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}
else{
    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}
```

In IBAction use

```
 UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
 if(button.backgroundColor==[UIColor blackColor]){
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [button setSelected:YES];
}
else{
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [button setSelected:NO];
}
```

Comment: this was not working. i already changing the colour of the button when it created by viewWithTag.

Comment: Instead of calling with tag values yu can you add subview in cells orElse you can use tableviewcell subclasses